# Why does GetUserInfoAsync() complain on "Bearer token not found"?

Tags: oauth, identityserver4, access-token

Here's my code :

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var firstResponse = await client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
        {
            Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,

            ClientId = "roclient.reference",
            ClientSecret = "secret",

            UserName = "bob",
            Password = "Pass123$",
            Scope = "resource1.scope1 resource2.scope1"
        });


        var result = await client.GetUserInfoAsync(new UserInfoRequest
        {
            Address = disco.UserInfoEndpoint,

            ClientId = "api1",
            ClientSecret = "secret",
            Token = firstResponse.AccessToken
        });

        if (result.IsError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result.Error);
        }
```

As a result, I get "Bearer token not found" on my identity server side and "Unauthorized" on the client. What should I do to make GetUserInfoAsync() correctly working with passed access token? Meanwhile, IntrospectTokenAsync() works with the same access token flawlessly.

Comment: I would inspect the request to the UserInfo endpoint in Fiddler to see why it fails? https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

Comment: Tried to run Fiddler, got the following request view:

https://i.imgur.com/YfFSuZj.png

Why did it add me 'Basic' token instead of 'Bearer'?

Comment: basic is the clientid+secret base64 encoded.

Comment: Yes, I know what basic is but why it's substituted instead of explicitly passed 'Bearer'?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I get the userinfo using an access token in C#:

```
    var response = await client.GetUserInfoAsync(new UserInfoRequest
    {
        Address = disco.UserInfoEndpoint,
        Token = accessToken
    });
```

Perhaps the solution is not to provide the clientid+secret?